# Upgrade Java 16 to Java 17 in 32bit Raspberry

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, 32-bit, java-17

Installing the latest version of Java is always a bit messy and wanted to see if I'm doing everything right.
I currently have Java 16 in this path `/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-16-hotspot-armhf`

I followed the following tutorial [2) Install OpenJDK 17 on Debian 10/9](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-openjdk-on-debian-linux/) and everything went OK.

My `JAVA_HOME` is correct and set to `/opt/jdk17`, but my `java --version` is still using Java 16.

```sh
java --version
openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9)
OpenJDK Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9, mixed mode)
```

Other useful information

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which java
/usr/bin/java

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PATH
/home/pi/.local/bin:/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

My **PATH** variable doesn't seem to contain `/opt/jdk-17` but even after running `source /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` and `/opt/jdk-17` present, `java --version` is still using Java 16.

Comment: can you take a look at you `PATH` variable and run `which java`?

Comment: can you run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`?

Comment: ```pi@raspberrypi:/opt $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-16-hotspot-armhf/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

Comment: Did you hit '$sudo apt autoremove' after finishing the download or have you tried deleting the old java packages?

Comment: That `PATH` doesn’t include `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: Make sure to follow the steps in those instructions starting from “Configure Java environment”

Comment: @TimMoore I followed the step :c idk why it didnt work, what can I do to permanetly do it?

Comment: Did you also follow the next step? `source /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`. If that isn’t working, try opening a new shell. If that still doesn’t work, there must be something else in your shell configuration overwriting `PATH`.

Comment: @TimMoore yes I did that and when I run that command /opt/jdk appears in PATH but java --version still uses 16

Comment: I guess those instructions assume that you don’t have another Java version installed in a location earlier in the `PATH`. If you can’t uninstall Java 16, try swapping the order to ensure the Java 17 directory is at the start of the `PATH`: `export PATH=\$JAVA_HOME/bin:\$PATH`

Comment: @TimMoore I can uninstall Java 16 I just want to know how to properly do that

Comment: Alternatively, if you follow the other instructions in the document to install using `apt`, it might simplify things for you. Then, some of the other suggestions in the comments will work.

Comment: apt doesn't work because is Debian 11

Comment: I’m not an expert on Debian/Raspberry Pi (and this is getting off topic for Stack Overflow) but Apt has been part of Debian for many years. The command may be called `apt-get` in your version.

Comment: apt is avaible but that package isnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the various comments ...

1. You have Java 17 installed ... manually ... in `/opt/jdk17`
2. You have `JAVA_HOME` pointing on the base of the Java 17 installation.  I assume that there is (for example) a `/opt/jdk17/bin/java` executable.
3. The Java 17 installation directory is NOT on the command search path (`PATH`).
4. The search path is finding `/usr/bin/java` ... which (in your case) says Java 16 when you run `java -version`.
5. Your system has the "/etc/alternatives" system installed, but `sudo update-alternatives --config java` says that only Java 16 is available.

So ...

The "alternatives" mechanism creates and maintains symlinks to various switchable commands.  If you run `ls -l /usr/bin/java` for example, I expect that you will see that it is a symlink.  When you run `update-alternatives`, it will attempt to update the symlinks.  But it can only do this for commands and command versions that it knows about.

Right now ... `update-alternatives` does not know about Java 17.  It doesn't know it is installed, or where it is installed.

If you had installed Java 17 from the package manager, then the config files that tell `update-alternatives` about Java 17 would have been added too.

Solutions, ordered from "best" (1) to "worst".

1. Remove your manual install of Java 17 and install it from the package manager.  You might need to find / add an "experimental" Debian package repo to do this.  (I get the impression that the official Debian repo managers tend to be rather slow in picking up new stuff.)
2. Carefully read the documentation in `man 1 update-alternatives` and `update-alternatives --help` and then use the `--install` and `--slave` commands to tell it about Java 17.
3. Find the Java symlinks and manually replace them with symlinks to the Java 17 versions of the executables.  (Be careful ...)
4. Add `/opt/jdk17/bin` to the start of your `PATH`.  (Be careful ...)
5. Just use the full pathnames; e.g. `/opt/jdk17/bin/java` rather than `java`.

---

I also came across this:

- [Java 17 on the Raspberry Pi](https://foojay.io/today/java-17-on-the-raspberry-pi/) which includes (among other things) example commands for adding Java 17 to the alternatives system.  It also mentions using `sdkman`.
- [How to Install Java 17 (JDK 17) on Debian 11](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-java-17-jdk-17-on-debian-11/).  There is a comment that says:

  > "*Awesome! Thanks. This Debian package works on Raspberry Pi's Raspian 64-bit Bullseye as of posting. Only method that works without manually downloading packages and *attempting* to install. :)"*.

  But I see that you have a 32-bit Raspberry Pi ...

Comment: Acutally option number 5 worked great because I only upgraded to Java17 because it was required to run Minecraft 1.18, this way I maintain Java normally but launch the Minecrafr Server Service with `/opt/jdk17/bin/java`